# Spring Security support local account and social account

Tags: facebook, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-social

following this tutorial [Petri article](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/adding-social-sign-in-to-a-spring-mvc-web-application-registration-and-login/#comment-1413591)
I am trying to create the same application with spring boot, but without hibernate, just Jdbc, since I've learnt hibernate yet.

I've created a project base on [this tutorial](http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2014/09/02/adding-social-login-to-a-website-using-spring-social/) first, 
so far I understand the followings:

1. use spring security and jdbc to create a local login application.
2. login with spring social and read feed, just like spring social sample quickstart
3. create local account with social information, login with social account.

Then I try to further modify it to support local user. But there are a few problems which I still could not solve. 
Here is [my source code](https://github.com/maxiwu/SocialLogin)

1. I look into Petri's project, couldn't find any controller that handle login POST, does this mean by configuring spring security correctly, it handles it for us? 
   My application needs me to explicitly write method to handle login POST which I learn from some spring social example.
2. My project is not functioning properly, If I local in with a registered local user, it does render the /home, but the url is showing /login. and if I request for /home again, it bounces me back and render login page.
   If I login with social user, I am trying facebook, it does redirect me to facebook login and after login, gives me 403 error.
   I think this is caused by spring security not correctly configure, I just not yet figure out how.
3. The spring social sample use a Form POST with /signin/facebook, with a hidden field name 'scope' which define facebook scope, for example email,user_friends,user_posts,user_about_me.
   But Petri's sample is using hyperlink /auth/facebook without any scope. What is the difference between /signin/facebook and /auth/facebook? How do I defined scope with a hyperlink? Do I need to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Please read official documentation carefully: [spring-social reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)
It will explain you everything.

Difference between signin and auth is explained in chapter 4.1 and 4.2. Briefly:

> Therefore, to initiate a provider sign-in flow via
>   SocialAuthenticationFilter, you can simply provide a link to
>   "/auth/{providerid}" on a web page.

and singin is for ProviderSignInController.

As for bullet number 1. Yes, this part of code tells spring to setup something for you:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                //Configures form login
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login/authenticate")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error=bad_credentials")
```

Sorry, can't speak of number 2. You will have to dive deeper into documentation and example. I suggest to start from cloning and running existing demos and projects to figure out what you missed in your configuration.